# Build different production builds of react app differing by part of implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, package.json

I created my react app with create-react-app script.
I would like to achieve possibility to build 2 different versions of react app which differs by, let's say, single function?

Let's consider 2 possible implementations of `fetchSth()` - one would do http GET to some backend, another would call WASM compiled version of backend bundled to module of `fetchSth()`. These 2 `fetchSth()` cant exist simultaneously so there cannot be some runtime check.

It sounds like there would be need some sort of changing dispatching in imports.

I would achieve that by juggling with symlinks, but is there less barbaric way to achieve this, by let's say defining some environmental variable or passing sth to `npm build`?

I use typescript version of react if it differs.